# R rank points in plot

Tags: r, plot, rank

I have a question about plots. For example we have variable a and b, we plot this in R and you get the point. Now, I want to make a range of best/highest point. Is there a way to generate a ranking in the point? I thought maybe something with mean?

Thanks!

```
a<- c(1,3,7,5,3,8,4,5,3,6,9,4,2,6,3)
b<- c(5,3,7,2,7,2,5,2,7,3,6,2,1,1,9)
plot(a,b)
```

Comment: Do you mean to `order` the points by value?

Comment: You should really clarify a bit what exactly you want. For a ranking, you can simply do `rank(b)`, but I'm far from sure if that's what you need.

Comment: what i want is the 5 points with the highest values. So I want to rank all the points so i could extract the 5 i need.. it is a little bit clear now?

Comment: `head(sort(b), n = 5)` ? Maybe you want that but I don't get how want to rank them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment to get the positions of the points with the 5 highest `b` values, use `order`:

```
order(b,decreasing=T)[1:5]
[1] 15  3  5  9 11
```

And you can use this to get the relevant `a` and `b` values:

```
a[order(b,decreasing=T)[1:5]]
[1] 3 7 3 3 9
b[order(b,decreasing=T)[1:5]]
[1] 9 7 7 7 6
```

You can use this also to highlight them in the plot:

```
high <- order(b,decreasing=T)[1:5]
col <- rep("black",length(b))
col[high] <- "red"
plot(a,b,col=col)
```

[image: plot of data]

Note that there is some overplotting here (2 values at (3,7))

Comment: I think that is close to the solution, but if you print the whole list, point 14 is higher than 13 and I think that is not right

Comment: Point 14 and point 13 both have a `b` value of 1, what exactly do you mean by higher?

Comment: The a by 14 has a 6 and the 13 has an 1.

Comment: The 13 has a 2 surely? So are you wanting the ranking done by the `a` value? If so, then just put `a` instead of `b` as the argument to `order`.